# Google App Engine Java: Query on a child object

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Question is related to Google app engine Java.

I have two objects Employee, Address.
Each employee has a list of addresses init and also has a String status of current/retired/left/fired.

Now I want to get a list of all my current employees who are Houston based.

```
Class Employee {
    @Persistent(mappedBy="employee")
    List<Address> addresses;
    String status;
}

Class Address {
    @Persistent 
    private Employee employee;
    String address1;
    String city;
    String zip;
}
```

On my db class how do tell my query to do what i need.

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Employee.class, whereClause.toString());

List<Employee> empList = (List<Employee>) query.executeWithArray(paramValues.toArray());
```

When I set my status parameter to current, it will give me a list of current employees, how do i add the condition of "Houston" into my query so that I dont have to do the filter by myself.

I feel that I am missing something. Appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1):

This would require a join, and so isn't possible in a query on App Engine. Your best option would be to query on all address entities from Houston, then fetch their Employee records and filter (in memory) by status.

Comment: I was doing the same but over the period the resultset size has grown and now i am getting the 35second limit exception. Tried to do the pagination to avoid it but soon ran into the issue of some pages showing no result because of the filter on the page.

Comment: @oceandrive In that case, you'll need to modify your data model - for instance, by copying the status flag to all an employee's address entities.

Comment: ya, had the same thing on mind but felt too much data duplication. But I feel that I might have to take this approach. thanks for the response.